# Why am I getting the following upload error and how do I fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, sign, developer-console, zipalign

I signed my apk using the command:

> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
>   MyFocusKeystore.keystore
>   C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity_Projects\Shapes\Focus.apk myfocus

and zipaligned it using the command:

> zipalign -v 4 "C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\jre\bin\Focus.apk" "C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\jre\bin\Focus-zipaligned.apk"

I verified everything and uploaded it in Google Developer Console. But I got the below upload error:

> RSA uses digest algorithm SHA-256 and signature algorithm RSA which is
>   not supported on API Level(s) 16-17 for which this APK is being
>   verified.

[image: Error that I got in Google Developer Console]

Could someone help me fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren’t just relying on Unity’s signing?

Comment: Yes.Here is the reason:  https://answers.unity.com/questions/1538542/how-to-fix-you-uploaded-an-apk-with-an-invalid-sig.html

Answer (score 1):

Add the flag `-sigalg SHA1withRSA` to the command.

The default value of this flag is `SHA256withRSA` and SHA256 is not supported on SDK 16 and 17 apparently.

Note that if you switch to using [`apksigner`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner) (available in SDK Tools) to sign your app, you won't have to think about this since it will automatically select the best algorithms for your app based on the `minSdkVersion`. If you decide to switch (which I'd recommend you to), keep in mind that you'll need to sign *after* you zip-align.

Comment: Is it like this: jarsigner -verbose -sigalg=SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore MyFocusKeystore.keystore Focus.apk mygame ?? If not could you rewrite my command with your suggestion?please?

Comment: That's right. You probably don't need the "=" sign actually, I realize. I'll update my answer.

Comment: But that's how I did initially right?check my question description

Comment: Anyway...I did it with apksigner manually and uploaded the apk successfully  :)

Comment: Mhm, that's strange then. Maybe you had previously signed the APK without the -sigalg flag? I don't know. Glad you sorted it out eventually :)